# Flutter IOS product flavors not running

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I have implemented product flavors in my flutter app and i have add three different google-services.plist files. Now when I try to run my ios app it throws this error.
I followed this medium post [link](https://medium.com/@matt.goodson.business/separating-build-environment-configurations-in-flutter-with-firebase-doing-it-the-right-way-c72c3ad3621f)

Xcode's output:

```
error: Multiple commands produce
'/Users/abc/MarkiTech/pulscare_mobile/build/ios/Debug-development-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist':
1) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/abc/Downloads/development/GoogleService-Info.plist' to
'/Users/abc/MarkiTech/pulscare_mobile/build/ios/Debug-development-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
2) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/abc/Downloads/master/GoogleService-Info.plist' to
'/Users/abc/MarkiTech/pulscare_mobile/build/ios/Debug-development-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
3) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/abc/Downloads/stage/GoogleService-Info.plist' to
'/Users/abc/MarkiTech/pulscare_mobile/build/ios/Debug-development-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
```

Comment: Do your Bundle Resources of Runner target contain `GoogleService-Info.plist`?

Answer (score 17):

If your Runner target contains `GoogleService-Info.plist` in Bundle Resources try this:

1. Open your iOS workspace in Xcode
2. Tap `Runner` project in project navigator (left panel with files)
3. Tap `Runner` in TARGETS list
4. Go to `Build Phases` tab
5. Expand `Copy Bundle Resources`
6. Remove `GoogleService-Info.plist` from Bundle Resources

Comment: Issue resolved. Had two GoogleServices-Info.plist in copy bundle resources. Removed one and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks !! This solved my issue on " Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')" when using flavors